# Joining nested tables with conditions in MySQL and Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building an application on `Laravel 7` where I'm having following models:

**Company** (table name `companies`)

```
id      name             created_at
 1  Sample company 1   2018-09-17 17:47:03
```

**Contracts** (table name `contract_awards`)

```
id        name                 company_id  project_id   created_at
1   Sample Project involved        1            1     2018-09-17 17:47:03
```

**Project** (table name `projects`)

```
id        name                  state          region
1      Sample Project 1       XYZ State      ABC Region
```

**Categories**

```
id    name
1     Residential
2     Commercial
```

**categories_projects_table**

```
id   categories_id    project_id
1        2                   1
```

Currently I'm fetching the companies and project details, where in companies are being fetched with its own filters/parameters and projects are being fetched with its own filters/parameters, I'm able to join projects table and fetch the result as per condition but while applying categories filter I'm unable to fetch the data. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correct or not, my code is following:

```php
Company::leftjoin('contract_awards', function ($join) {
    $join->on('companies.id', '=', 'contract_awards.awarded_by');
})
->leftjoin('projects', function ($q) {
    $q->on('contract_awards.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
    ->when(request('state'), function ($q) {
        $q->whereIn('state', collect(request('state')->pluck('id')));
    })
    ->when(request('region'), function ($q) {
        $q->whereIn('region', collect(request('region'))->pluck('id'));
    })
    ->when(request('categories'), function ($q) {
        $q->leftjoin('categories_projects_table', function($q) {
            $q->on('projects.id', '=', 'categories_projects_table.project_id');
        })
        // currently checking with static IDs later will be changed to collect(request('categories'))->pluck('id')
        ->select('categories_projects_table.categories_id as project_categories_id')
        ->whereIn('project_categories_id', [1]);
    });
})
->select('companies.*', 'projects.name as project_name', 'projects.area as project_area')
->paginate(15);
```

I mean to say that I want to filter projects with its category relation, Above code gives me error:

> column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'project_categories_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `companies` left join `contract_awards` on `companies`.`id .........

Any better approach in executing this is most welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: when you use where queries, you need to use the actual column name, not its alias. (`categories_id` instead of `project_categories_id`)